# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "stdin" error when trying to copy_from redshift

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, stdin, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am having this problem when I am trying to copy to AWS redshift.
This is the code I am trying to run:

```
with open('path/to/files, 'rb') as fo:
    cursor.copy_from(fo, 'schema.table', sep=',')
    cursor.commit()
```

And I encountered the error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "stdin" 
LINE 1: ...Y schema.table FROM stdin WITH...
```

I am running python 3.5 with psycopg2.
Hope that you guys can help! Thx in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AWS Redshift is not PostgreSQL, though it supports a subset of PostgreSQL syntax and functionality.

It does not have `COPY ... FROM STDIN`.

See [the manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) for how to use `COPY` on Redshift.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CraigRinger  I understand your point and see how COPY is usedfrom a command line or a DB tool (DBeaver, etc), but how do you do a copy to a table from within a python script.  What module and syntax would you suggest?

Comment: You probably have to use multi-inserts instead, or generate data to upload to s3 and `COPY` from there. *shrug*. I don't use Redshift. Maybe you should post a new question and link back to this one?

Answer (score 0):

check this solution [Python psycopg2 insert NULL in some rows in postgresql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54428797/python-psycopg2-insert-null-in-some-rows-in-postgresql-table/54429376?noredirect=1#comment95701535_54429376)

for insert multiple rows or python dataframe in Redshift