# Python psycopg2 insert NULL in some rows in postgresql table

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I have a Python dataframe with NULL value in some rows, while inserting to postgresql, some null in datetype column turns into 'NaT' string or 'NaN', I like it to be a real NULL , which is nothing in that cell.

sample dataframe before insert

[image]

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

conn=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'myDB', host='amazonaws.com', 
port= '2222', user= 'mysuser', password= 'mypass')
cur = conn.cursor()

df= pd.DataFrame({ 'zipcode':[1,np.nan,22,88],'city':['A','h','B',np.nan]})


subset = df[['zipcode', 'city']]
data = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]
records_list_template = ','.join(['%s'] * len(data)) 
insert_query = 'insert into public.MyTable (zipcode, city) values {}'.format(records_list_template)
cur.execute(insert_query, data)
conn.commit()
```

result in postgresql table

[image]

expected result below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert `NaN` to `None` in this way:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'zipcode':[1,np.nan,22,88],
    'city':['A','h','B',np.nan],
    'date':['2019-01-01','2019-01-02',pd.NaT,pd.NaT]})

df['date'] = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if not pd.isnull(d) else None for d in df['date']]

subset = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
```

See [DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html?highlight=dataframe%20where#pandas.DataFrame.where)

Comment: my bad, my actual table contains a datetype column which has some NaT,  the df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None) can't convert NaT

Comment: Indeed, it does not work with `NaT` (I thought it should). I added a conversion from `NaT` to None in a specific column, see the updated answer.

Comment: by the way, do you know how to speed up the process if I have 1 millions rows to insert? Bulk insert?

Comment: Do you have the data in a file?

Comment: it's in pandas dataframe, I can save it as a csv.

Comment: Two options. 1. Save data to csv and use [`copy_from()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from). 2. Use [`execute_values()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) - much more efficient than inserting row by row.

Comment: copy_from() only work in PostgreSQL, unfortunate, I'm using AWS Redshift. execute_values()  will work in Redshift, but very slow, i just tested it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Convert all instances of NaN in the dataframe by replacing with None, like this:

```
df = df.replace({pd.np.nan: None})
```

Comment: if you do this, than there will be 'None' in the postgres db. the OP wants to have [null] in the db