# Speed up to_sql() when writing Pandas DataFrame to Oracle database using SqlAlchemy and cx_Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

Using pandas dataframe's to_sql method, I can write a small number of rows to a table in oracle database pretty easily:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<host>)(PORT=1521))\
       (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=<servicename>)))"
pwd = input('Please type in password:')
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://myusername:' + pwd + '@%s' % dsn_tns)
df.to_sql('test_table', engine.connect(), if_exists='replace')
```

But with any regular-sized dataframes (mine has 60k rows, not so big), the code became unusable as it never finished in the time I was willing to wait (definitely more than 10 min). I've googled and searched quite a few times and the closest solution was the answer given by [ansonw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748781/ansonw) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997859/bulk-insert-a-pandas-dataframe-using-sqlalchemy). But that one was about mysql, not oracle. As [Ziggy Eunicien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2716837/ziggy-eunicien) pointed out, it did not work for oracle. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here's a sample of rows in the dataframe:

```
id          name            premium     created_date    init_p  term_number uprate  value   score   group   action_reason
160442353   LDP: Review     1295.619617 2014-01-20  1130.75     1           7       -42 236.328243  6       pass
164623435   TRU: Referral   453.224880  2014-05-20  0.00        11          NaN     -55 38.783290   1       suppress
```

and here is the data types for the df:

```
id               int64
name             object
premium          float64
created_date     object
init_p           float64
term_number      float64
uprate           float64
value            float64
score            float64
group            int64
action_reason    object
```

Comment: Can you provide a runnable test case? With the corresponding SQL for creating and populating the table with dummy data? There could be any number of issues that you are running into.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Pandas + SQLAlchemy per default save all `object` (string) columns as **CLOB** in Oracle DB, which makes insertion **extremely** slow.

Here are some tests:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine

#######################################################
### DB connection strings config
#######################################################
tns = """
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my-db-scan)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = my_service_name)
    )
  )
"""

usr = "test"
pwd = "my_oracle_password"

engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://%s:%s@%s' % (usr, pwd, tns))

# sample DF [shape: `(2000, 11)`]
# i took your 2 rows DF and replicated it: `df = pd.concat([df]* 10**3, ignore_index=True)`
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
```

DF info:

```
In [61]: df.shape
Out[61]: (2000, 11)

In [62]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2000 entries, 0 to 1999
Data columns (total 11 columns):
id               2000 non-null int64
name             2000 non-null object
premium          2000 non-null float64
created_date     2000 non-null datetime64[ns]
init_p           2000 non-null float64
term_number      2000 non-null int64
uprate           1000 non-null float64
value            2000 non-null int64
score            2000 non-null float64
group            2000 non-null int64
action_reason    2000 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4), int64(4), object(2)
memory usage: 172.0+ KB
```

Let's check how long will it take to store it to Oracle DB:

```
In [57]: df.shape
Out[57]: (2000, 11)

In [58]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 df.to_sql('test_table', engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
1 loop, best of 1: 16 s per loop
```

In Oracle DB (pay attention at CLOB's):

```
AAA> desc test.test_table
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ------------------
 ID                                       NUMBER(19)
 NAME                                     CLOB        #  !!!
 PREMIUM                                  FLOAT(126)
 CREATED_DATE                             DATE
 INIT_P                                   FLOAT(126)
 TERM_NUMBER                              NUMBER(19)
 UPRATE                                   FLOAT(126)
 VALUE                                    NUMBER(19)
 SCORE                                    FLOAT(126)
 group                                    NUMBER(19)
 ACTION_REASON                            CLOB        #  !!!
```

Now let's instruct pandas to save all `object` columns as VARCHAR data types:

```
In [59]: dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(df[c].str.len().max())
    ...:         for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}
    ...:

In [60]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 df.to_sql('test_table', engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype=dtyp)
1 loop, best of 1: 335 ms per loop
```

This time it was approx. 48 times faster

Check in Oracle DB:

```
 AAA> desc test.test_table
 Name                          Null?    Type
 ----------------------------- -------- ---------------------
 ID                                     NUMBER(19)
 NAME                                   VARCHAR2(13 CHAR)        #  !!!
 PREMIUM                                FLOAT(126)
 CREATED_DATE                           DATE
 INIT_P                                 FLOAT(126)
 TERM_NUMBER                            NUMBER(19)
 UPRATE                                 FLOAT(126)
 VALUE                                  NUMBER(19)
 SCORE                                  FLOAT(126)
 group                                  NUMBER(19)
 ACTION_REASON                          VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)        #  !!!
```

Let's test it with 200.000 rows DF:

```
In [69]: df.shape
Out[69]: (200000, 11)

In [70]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 df.to_sql('test_table', engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype=dtyp, chunksize=10**4)
1 loop, best of 1: 4.68 s per loop
```

It took ~5 seconds for 200K rows DF in my test (not the fastest) environment.

**Conclusion:** use the following trick in order to explicitly specify `dtype` for all DF columns of `object` dtype when saving DataFrames to Oracle DB. Otherwise it'll be saved as CLOB data type, which requires special treatment and makes it very slow

```
dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(df[c].str.len().max())
        for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}

df.to_sql(..., dtype=dtyp)
```

Comment: Thanks. On my data, after specifying the 2 "object" columns to VARCHAR type, the execution time went from over 30 minutes to a couple seconds!

Comment: @breezymri, glad i could help :)

Comment: @MaxU I'm on Python 3.6, but my types doesn't have any VARCHAR (or similar). Any hint there?

Comment: @mstuebner, what do you mean? You have an SQL Alchemy version, which doesn’t have such type??

Comment: @MaxU My This type comes from "types" doesn't it? I just found that types doesn't have a VARCHAR,

Comment: @mstuebner, what is your sqlalchemy version?

Comment: @MaxU make sure you called  - - from sqlalchemy import types

Comment: I'm getting an error: `raise ValueError(f"{col} ({my_type}) not a string")` I'm on python 3.6.8, pandas 1.1.3, sqlalchemy 1.3.20

Comment: @Vincent, thanks for the information! :-D If you have an error please open a new question and don’t forget to provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Awwesome from 1-hour plus loads to 3 seconds

Comment: @MaxU I was searching for this exact solution. I'm bookmarking this solution, since most of my python to oracle exports have string datatypes which are being imported to oracle databases as objects. +1

Comment: @MaxU-stopWARagainstUA, Can we also change `dtypes` of pandas dataframe to `varchar` when we `merge` to oracle using `executemany` ? does it improve performance if we're not using `to_sql` method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `method='multi'` and this will boost your data insertion speed.

You can also, adjust the `chunksize` as per your need, Depends on your data.

I found this when I tried to write a google cloud function which have ability to load data from csv files/excel into dataframe and I would like to save that dataframe to the postgresql database in google cloud sql.

This is the handy tool to use, if you can create a similar structure in the dataframe as in your database table.

```py
df.to_sql(
    'table_name',
    con=engine, 
    if_exists='append', 
    index=False, 
    chunksize=2000,
    method='multi'
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the Oracle database connector dialect `oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{pwd}@{oracle_database}`. Error: "sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: The 'oracle' dialect with current database version settings does not support in-place multirow inserts."

Answer (score 0):

Just commenting here for posterity. I'm on python 3.6.8, pandas 1.1.3, sqlalchemy 1.3.20. When I tried implementing the solution from MaxU, I was initially encountering an error:

```
raise ValueError(f"{col} ({my_type}) not a string")
```

I honestly don't know why. After spending a couple hours debugging, this is what finally worked for me. In my case, I was trying to read from a CSV and insert to Oracle:

```
import cx_Oracle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn = create_engine('oracle://{}:{}@{}'.format(USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE))

df = pd.read_csv(...)
object_columns = [c for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()]
dtyp = {c:sa.types.VARCHAR(df[c].str.len().max()) for c in object_columns}

df.to_sql(..., dtype=dtyp)
```

To be honest, I didn't really change much so not 100% sure why I was getting the original error, but just posting here in case it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:
This function will take dataframe name and length(optional).
It returns converted datatypes (object types) to Varchar(length) default lenght =250 (This fun only deals with Object types)

```
def dtyp(df_name, length=250):
    cols = df_name.select_dtypes(include='object')
    dtyps = {col: VARCHAR2(length) for col in cols}
    return dtypsenter code here
```

Calling Method Example:

```
config.dtyp(dataframe, 300)
```