# Converting NaN to Oracle Nulls within Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, null, sql-insert

I get this error on executing the below function & It is because NaN is tried to be inserted into numeric column. Replacing NaN with 0 throughout does work but replacement with None does not. Any ideas would be appreciated

```
def insertData(table_name, schema_name, df):
    if not df.empty:

        #input_data[file].fillna(0, inplace=True) # This works but replacing with 0's is not ideal
        df.where(pd.notnull(df), None) #This does not work
        values = df.to_dict(orient='records')
        table = sa.Table(table_name , conndict['meta'], autoload=True, schema=schema_name)
        result_proxy = conndict['conn'].execute(table.insert(), values)
        return result_proxy
    else:
        return None
```

> **(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1055: value is not a number (NaN) and cannot be used in Oracle numbers**

Comment: Btw `df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)` [returns a **new** DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with the replacements, so that line is a no-operation as is. With `inplace=True` the operation would take place in place, but that'd then change the `dtype` to object.

Answer (score 4):

well, Pandas has it's own beautiful [DataFrame.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method, which takes care of `NaN` --> `NULL` conversion automatically:

```
df.to_sql('tab_name', sql_alchemy_conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

PS in case your DF has string (`object`) columns - use `dtype` parameter ([see an example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42769557/5741205))

Comment: Thanks Max. I used to_sql earlier but later had to switch to CORE insert from SQLAlchemy due to performance issues. We even tried tuning/searchin options for a while wrt to_sql but it did not translate.

Comment: @VarunKhanna, what kind of DB are you using?

Comment: I am connecting to an Oracle DB

Comment: @VarunKhanna, did you check a linked answer? It addresses an issue when string Pandas columns are getting converted to CLOB's on the Oracle side, which causes a huge performance issues...

Comment: Yup. I checked that CLOBS were not getting stored. A describe on the table showed that strings were being stored as strings