# How to resolve cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1043: invalid number error?

Tags: sql, pandas, oracle

I have a pandas df like this:

```
      A         B       C             D            E       F        G        H
0  1033548.0   0.0  20190324.0   2019-04-13       NaT   10176.0    NaN  40360001.0
1  1033549.0   0.0  20190324.0   2019-04-13 2019-04-13   10182.0    NaN  41360562.0
2  1033550.0   0.0  20190324.0   2019-04-13       NaT   10433.0    NaN  45180156.0
3  1033551.0   0.0  20190324.0   2019-04-13       NaT   10019.0    123         NaN
4  1033552.0   0.0  20190324.0   2019-04-13       NaT   10333.0    NaN  40120165.0
5  1033553.0   0.0  20190324.0   2019-04-13       NaT   10246.0    NaN  40820596.0 
6  1033554.0   0.0  20190324.0          NaT       NaT   10107.0    NaN         NaN
7  1033555.0   0.0  20190324.0   2019-04-13       NaT   10131.0    NaN  41190549.0
8  1033556.0   0.0  20190324.0   2019-04-13       NaT   10057.0    NaN  40430581.0
9  1033557.0   0.0  20190324.0   2019-04-13       NaT   10009.0    NaN  40360012.0
```

I want to write this df to my `Oracle Database Table` using `SQL Insert Statement`. But since my df contains NaNs and NaTs, so its giving me error: `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1043: invalid number`.
How can I write this df to the oracle table using SQL which will not give me any error?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit the question and add the table structure as well.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299282/converting-nan-to-oracle-nulls-within-python-pandas

Answer (score 1):

Prachi.

Your column `G` is of type `number` in Oracle, right? Thus, I believe you need to set your `NaN`s with 0 (zeros), if possible.

Or make 2 types of inserts:

1. With column `G`, if it is exists on `DF`;
2. Without column `G`, if it **doesn't** exists on `DF`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace your {float} nan by None in the binding list.

```
import math

bind_insert = lines_to_insert_df.values.tolist()

for b in bind_insert :

    for index, value in enumerate(b):
        if isinstance(value, float) and math.isnan(value):
            b[index] = None
        elif isinstance(value, type(pd.NaT)):
            b[index] = None

con.cursor().executemany(query, bind_insert)
```

Comment: Thanks elena.kim.
There is the same issue for not a time data (Nat).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I do not think it is a `NaN` issue since it works ok for me with `NaN` values.

In my case there was a float column that had `inf` values due to divide by 0. Once I took care of this, the write to Oracle issue went away.