# How to speed up insert a dataframe with 4 million rows into a table by using slqalchemy and mysql

Tags: mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a dataframe with 4 million rows, I use to_sql to insert it into an exist table, but it takes almost 2 hours to finish the insert, is there a way to speed up?

I use this method:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, types

def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter):
    data = [dict((k,v) for k, v in zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
    conn.execute(self.insert_statement().values(data))
    df.to_sql(raw_table_name[i], con=db, index=False, if_exists='append',chunksize=50000)
```

[Method website](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8953)

is there a way to speed up?

Comment: df.to_sql(..., dtype=dtyp), specific the data type in you data frame will speed up the whole process . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727990/speed-up-to-sql-when-writing-pandas-dataframe-to-oracle-database-using-sqlalch

Comment: I also tried this method, but it still takes more than one hour to insert.