# Time complexity of SQL insert and degrading performance with database size - pyspark parquet files to sql via pandas `to_sql()`

Tags: sql, pandas, performance, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Appending to a SQLite database iteratively using pandas `to_sql()` functionality appears to be decreasing in its performance with every iteration.

The dataframe that I am appending within each iteration is approximately the same size, but the database is obviously increasing in size.

Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
  # par_dir is the parquet directory containing thousands of parquet files for a table

  parquet_files = os.listdir(par_dir)
  for f in tqdm(parquet_files):
    f_path = os.path.join(par_dir, f)
    if f.startswith('.'): continue
    if int(os.path.getsize(f_path))==0: continue

    df = pd.read_parquet(f_path)

    # self._cx is a connection to a sqlite database
    # self.if_exists is 'replace' on first loop and 'append' on every other loop
    df.to_sql(table_name,
              con=self._cx,
              if_exists=self.if_exists,
              chunksize=10000)
```

The performance of each insert to the database degrades with each file added as shown here:

[image]

Or in log-log space:

[image]

I assumed that a SQL insert time complexity would be dependent only on the number of rows of the data to be inserted (`df` in the code above) *not* on the size of the existing database.

Why would this time complexity of insertion be dependent upon the database size for which the data is being inserted, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It depends on your table schema, indexes, distribution of primary key values, how often the b-tree pages need to be split and rebalanced, etc. etc.

Comment: since you have also replace in your logic it is not independent from the database size. Also I cannot see, if you close the connection, or how many concurrent connection is active, which also can have affect on the performance.

Comment: @Shawn There are no primary keys in the data, and the 'replace' is only used on the first file addition, the rest are appending.  This is a sqlite database, so AFAIK there are no concurrent connections allowed.  The connection is held open the entire time by the database object, for which this function is a member.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options you can try to speed up:

1. Make all inserts in one transaction like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997859/bulk-insert-a-pandas-dataframe-using-sqlalchemy)
2. Insert into a new temporary table and then `insert into ... select ...`

Example:

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM   sourceTable
```

3. Like 2 but after the new table creation concatenate two tables into a new one

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
  SELECT v1
   FROM t1
  UNION
  SELECT v2
  FROM t2
```