# Bulk Insert from Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, bulkinsert

Can i do Bulk Insert from dataframe instead from a csv file

here is my code

```
sql = " BULK INSERT " + str(tbl_name) + "  FROM '" + fl_path + "' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,FIELDTERMINATOR='',ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',CODEPAGE = '65001'); "
engine.execute(text(sql).execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk insert a Pandas DataFrame using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997859/bulk-insert-a-pandas-dataframe-using-sqlalchemy)

Comment: @TeemuRisikko No, that doesn't answer my question