# Bulk insert from Python list/dict to Oracle Database using cx_Oracle executemany()

Tags: python, database, oracle, bulkinsert, cx-oracle

I am inserting data from a Python dictionary to Oracle DB. I used executemany() from cursor class. I get the following error:

**ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number**

Also, when I use try/except for executemany() I get an additional error:

**cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1010: not connected**

Environment: 
Python: 3.6.7, Oracle: 12c, cx_Oracle: 7.1.2, OS: Ubuntu

I converted the Dictionary data to a List of Dictionary and passed that as the second parameter of executemany(), but get the same errors.
Here is how my list of dictionaries looks like

```
    [{'location': 1, 'xxx_id': 917985, 'seq': 758, 'event_time': 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 5, 20, 1, 53), 'event_type': 'xxxx', 'number': 
    123, 'stop': '40305', 'x': None, 'y': None, 'arrival_time': 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 5, 20, 1, 33), 'departure_time': 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 5, 20, 2), 'yyy_id': 529934, 'zzz_id': 59359277}, 
   {'location': 1, 'xxx_id': 917985, 'seq': 759, 'event_time': 
   datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 5, 20, 2, 33), 'event_type': 'xxxx', 'number': 
   123, 'stop': '40301', 'x': None, 'y': None, 'arrival_time': 
   datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 5, 20, 2, 27), 'departure_time': 
   datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 5, 20, 2, 50), 'yyy_id': 529930, 'zzz_id': 59279},

   {.......},
   {.......}
   ]
```

Tried other recommendations from stackoverflow, but no luck. the closest to my situation is this one. [Insert a list of dictionaries into an SQL table using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636191/insert-a-list-of-dictionaries-into-an-sql-table-using-python)

Here is my code I tried

```
    sql_insert = '''INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (LOCATION, XXX_ID, SEQ, 
    EVENT_TIME, EVENT_TYPE, NUMBER, STOP, X, Y, ARRIVAL_TIME, DEPARTURE_TIME, 
    YYY_ID, ZZZ_ID)
    VALUES(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11, :12, :13)'''

    for k1, v1 in events.items():
        list_events = []
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            x = dict(v2)
            # print(x)
            list_events.append(x)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.executemany(sql_insert, list_events)
            connection.commit()
        except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
            print(e)
```

I am trying to insert few thousands of records. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague of mine suggested to use named(e.g. values(:location, :peggo_id, ....) placeholder instead of numbered placeholder and it worked with the named placeholder. Though I am not sure whether it is a Oracle or cx_Oracle thing. Also, the named parameters have to be exactly same as the key name in the dictionary, if you are passing the dictionary in executemany() method.

Answer (score 0):

See [Efficient and Scalable Batch Statement Execution in Python cx_Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle).

You want something like:

```
data = [
    (60, "Parent 60"),
    (70, "Parent 70"),
    (80, "Parent 80"),
    (90, "Parent 90"),
    (100, "Parent 100")
]

cursor.executemany("""
        insert into ParentTable (ParentId, Description)
        values (:1, :2)""", data)
```