# insert a list of Ordered Dictionaries to SQL table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have list of `OrderedDicts` the order of keys is correct, there is 72 keys in each dictionary,How can I write them to SQL table,

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import OperationalError
#code here
#my_list=list of OrderedDicts

conn = sqlite3.connect('test3.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

I checked [Insert a list of dictionaries into an SQL table using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636191/insert-a-list-of-dictionaries-into-an-sql-table-using-python),

```
cursor.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        mytable
        (id, price, type)
    VALUES
        (%(key1)s, %(key2)s, %(key3)s, ...(key72))
""", lst) # there must be a more pythonic way of performing this.
```

What I want is way of writing `my_list` into table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas to write directly, refer to [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) documentation.

```
import pandas
#your code
conn = sqlite3.connect('test3.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
df=pandas.DataFrame(my_list) # list of dictionaries
df.to_sql("name_of_table",conn)
conn.close()
```