# Speed up Python executemany

Tags: sql, python-3.x, odbc, pypyodbc

I'm inserting data from one database to another, so I have 2 connections (Conn1 and Conn2). Below is the code (using pypyodbc).

```
 import pypyodbc

 Conn1_Query = "SELECT column FROM Table"

 Conn1_Cursor.execute(Conn1_Query)
 Conn1_Data = Conn1_Cursor.fetchall()

 Conn1_array = []

 for row in Conn1_Data:
      Conn1_array.append(row)
```

The above part runs very quickly.

```
 stmt = "INSERT INTO TABLE(column) values (?)"
 Conn2_Cursor.executemany(stmt, Conn1_array)
 Conn2.commit()
```

This part is extremely slow. I've also tried to do a for loop to insert each row at a time using cursor.execute, but that is also very slow. What am I doing wrong and is there anything I can do to speed it up? Thanks for taking a look.

Thought I should also add that the Conn1 data is only ~50k rows. I also have some more setup code at the beginning that I didn't include because it's not pertinent to the question. It takes about 15 minutes to insert. As a comparison, it takes about 25 seconds to write the output to a csv file.

Comment: Where is your commit?

Comment: Apologies, just added it - I had it in my main body of code but didn't initially include it here. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `executemany` under pypyodbc sends separate INSERT statements for each row. It acts just the same as making individual `execute` calls in a loop. Given that pypyodbc is no longer under active development, that is unlikely to change.

However, if you are using a compatible driver like "ODBC Driver xx for SQL Server" and you switch to pyodbc then you can use its [fast_executemany](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany) option to speed up the inserts significantly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47057189/2144390) for more details.