# Python Bulk Insert gives TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have following code to insert multiple rows;

```
cnx = pymysql.connect(host='xx', user='xx', password='xx', database='xx', autocommit=True)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO `tableA`('id,'name',...)values(?,? ......)"
cursor.executemany(query, listTosave)
```

My listTosave contains values like;

```
[['AS0001', '1170', 1, '1', 'Unknown', 442, 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 28, 23, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 15, 11, 15), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 15, 10, 56), datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 28, 23, 18, 26), datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 28, 23, 59, 22), Decimal('15177.3184'), Decimal('15185.7562'), Decimal('8.4378')],[......],...
....]]
```

When I try to insert I get following error;

```
    cursor.executemany(query, listTosave)
  File "/tmp/pymodules/pymysql/cursors.py", line 194, in executemany
  File "/tmp/pymodules/pymysql/cursors.py", line 194, in <genexpr>
  File "/tmp/pymodules/pymysql/cursors.py", line 163, in execute
  File "/tmp/pymodules/pymysql/cursors.py", line 142, in mogrify
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I would like to insert multiple rows at once.

Comment: Is the line `query = "INSERT INTO 'tableA' ......` correct?

Comment: @ShivamSingh My query is like //"INSERT INTO `tableA` ('id',......)values (?,?,..)" I believe it is right

Comment: I think your issue is with the ```datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 28, 23, 0)```  convert it to  a string before the insert say ```str(datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 28, 23, 0))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listTosave` should be an list of tuples rather than list of lists

```
[('AS0001', '1170', 1, '1', 'Unknown', 442, 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 28, 23, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 15, 11, 15), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 15, 10, 56), datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 28, 23, 18, 26), datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 28, 23, 59, 22), Decimal('15177.3184'), Decimal('15185.7562'), Decimal('8.4378')),(......),...]
```

Comment: I changed it ..But getting another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615060/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-error-in-tuple-p