# Bulk insert gives TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mysql-python, python-2.x

I'm trying to save bunch of tuples in `MySqlDB`.

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO `TableA`
            (`clientid`,
           `createddatetime`,
           `siteid`,...)
        VALUES(%s,%s,%s,...)"""

cursor.executemany(query, listTosave)
```

My `listTosave` is like:

```
[('AS0001', '1170', '1', '1', 'Unknown', '442', '1', '2018-05-28 23:00:00', '2018-03-15 11:15:00', '2018-03-15 10:56:00', '2018-05-28 23:18:26', '2018-05-28 23:59:22', '15177.3184', '15185.7562', '8.4378', '1313.0547', '1313.6179', '0.5632', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '24.6518', '24.6518', '15101.7062', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '24.6563'), (.....)]
```

When executing , I get

```
    cursor.executemany(query , listTosave)
  File "/tmp/pymodules/pymysql/cursors.py", line 192, in executemany
  File "/tmp/pymodules/pymysql/cursors.py", line 208, in _do_execute_many
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

What Im doing wrong here?

p.s:

- My python version is 2.7.15. I pass correct number of arguments in my tuple list
- If I use ? instead of %s sign I get following error
  `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string`

Asked a question here:

[TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting Error in tuple python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615060/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-error-in-tuple-p/50615147?noredirect=1#comment88240455_50615147)

Comment: Standard response about why you dont want to do this because of the risk of [SQL Injection] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as well as a and mandatory reference to Bobby Tables here:
https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Double-check that all of the tuples in `listToSave` have the same number of items, and that is equal to the number of `%s` in the query.

Comment: You may have simplified your code for the sake of posting the question but you must be constructing the `listToSave` programmatically. So my suspicion is that `listToSave` while being a list and having all the elements may actually not be a list of `tuples`. So double check this additional nuance as well.