# utf_16_le_decode SystemError when inserting pandas DataFrame with fast_executemany

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

This is my code:

```
def insertDataFrameInDB(cursor, dataFrame, toTable, fieldNames = None):
    if fieldNames:
        dataFrame = dataFrame[fieldNames]
    else:
        fieldNames = dataFrame.columns

    for r in dataFrame.columns.values:
        dataFrame[r] = dataFrame[r].map(str)
        dataFrame[r] = dataFrame[r].map(str.strip)   
    params = [tuple(x) for x in dataFrame.values]

    fieldNameStr = ",".join(fieldNames)
    valueStr = ",".join(["?"] * len(fieldNames))
    sql = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES({})".format(toTable, fieldNameStr, valueStr)
    cursor.fast_executemany = True
    cursor.executemany(sql, params)
    cursor.commit()


insertDataFrameInDB(cursor, df, "table")
```

It gives the following error which I really can't address:

```
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
DataError: ('String data, right truncation: length 24 buffer 20', '22001')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py in decode(input, errors)
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 

SystemError: <built-in function utf_16_le_decode> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
SystemError: decoding with 'utf-16le' codec failed (SystemError: <built-in function utf_16_le_decode> returned a result with an error set)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py in decode(input, errors)
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 

SystemError: <built-in function utf_16_le_decode> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
SystemError: decoding with 'utf-16le' codec failed (SystemError: <built-in function utf_16_le_decode> returned a result with an error set)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f73d9346f943> in <module>()
     12 
     13 cursor = getCursor(conData)
---> 14 insertDataFrameInDB(cursor, df, "snowplow.sankey")

<ipython-input-1-69ecbca20fc8> in insertDataFrameInDB(cursor, dataFrame, toTable, fieldNames)
     29     sql = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES({})".format(toTable, fieldNameStr, valueStr)
     30     cursor.fast_executemany = True
---> 31     cursor.executemany(sql, params)
     32     cursor.commit()
SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an error set
```

A lot of error searching makes me think it has something to do with the lack of a BOM, I tried to decode the strings in the "params" tuples, also tried str.astype('U'). Does anybody know what causes the problem and possibly how to address that?

Comment: If you are using pyodbc 4.0.22 then try downgrading to 4.0.21 (`pip install pyodbc==4.0.21`) and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the error remains unfortunately

Comment: Do the errors persist if you use `cursor.fast_executemany = False` ...? Also, what ODBC driver are you using?

Comment: It is solved by setting cursor.fast_executemany = False, thanks! But I have a lot of data, and I read that with True it executes about 20 times faster. Isn't there a way to still use the fast_executemany?

Comment: `fast_executemany` may not be compatible with all ODBC drivers. Which driver are you using?

Comment: [ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]

Comment: My problem had nothing do with `executemany` but one of my columns contained python lists which resulted in the error above. So converting the column to string with: `df[col].astype(str)` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Microsoft's "ODBC Driver ... for SQL Server" so `fast_executemany` should work with pyodbc 4.0.21. However, you can invoke that feature while still using `DataFrame#to_sql` by using SQLAlchemy execution events as illustrated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48006551/2144390).

Example: The following code does not take advantage of `fast_executemany`

```python
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import time

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@SQL_panorama')

# test environment
num_rows = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[x, f'row{x:03}'] for x in range(num_rows)],
    columns=['id', 'txt']
)
#
cnxn = engine.connect()
try:
    cnxn.execute("DROP TABLE df_to_sql_test")
except:
    pass
cnxn.execute("CREATE TABLE df_to_sql_test (id INT PRIMARY KEY, txt NVARCHAR(50))")

# timing test
t0 = time.time()
df.to_sql("df_to_sql_test", engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
print(f"{num_rows} rows written in {(time.time() - t0):.1f} seconds")
```

Result:

```
1000 rows written in 25.2 seconds
```

Adding a SQLAlchemy execution event handler reduces the execution time significantly

```python
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
import time

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@SQL_panorama')

@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True


# test environment
num_rows = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[x, f'row{x:03}'] for x in range(num_rows)],
    columns=['id', 'txt']
)
#
cnxn = engine.connect()
try:
    cnxn.execute("DROP TABLE df_to_sql_test")
except:
    pass
cnxn.execute("CREATE TABLE df_to_sql_test (id INT PRIMARY KEY, txt NVARCHAR(50))")

# timing test
t0 = time.time()
df.to_sql("df_to_sql_test", engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
print(f"{num_rows} rows written in {(time.time() - t0):.1f} seconds")
```

Result:

```
1000 rows written in 1.6 seconds
```

For a more complete discussion of this approach, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48861231/2144390).