# DatabaseError: Write pandas dataframe to vertica using to_sql and vertica_python

Tags: python, pandas, vertica

I have a simple dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3], "B":["a", "b", "c"]})
```

I would like to write this dataframe to vertica database using to_sql method.  So I use vertica_python module and my code is the following

```
import pandas as pd
import vertica_python

cxn = {"user":'myuser',
       "password":'mypassword',
       "host":'xx.x.x.xx',
       "port":yyyy,
       "database":"mydb"}

engine = vertica_python.connect(**cxn)

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3], "B":["a", "b", "c"]})

df.to_sql("df", index=False, if_exists="replace", con=engine, schema="public", dtype={"A":"int", "B":"int"})
```

Then i got database error which i could not fix it as follows.

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

May I have your suggestions how to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: You have given type of B column as `int` convert it to `object` i.e., as `str` column

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into a similar problem connecting to `Vertica` and managed to create a connection via the following:

1. Using `sqlalchemy` and specifically [sqlalchemy-vertica](https://github.com/lv10/sqlalchemy-vertica)

As you seem to be using `vertica_python`, I would recommend installing with:

```py
pip install sqlalchemy-vertica[vertica-python]
```

This way you can connect the following way:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import vertica_python

engine = sa.create_engine('vertica+vertica_python://user:pwd@host:port/database')
```

**Note** that according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc), the upload with `pandas` and `sqlalchemy` can become a lot faster due to a recent improvement in sqlalchemy by passing the following configuration to `create_engine`:

```py
engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_url, fast_executemany=True)
```

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks promising. More on it on that answer.

**EDIT**

I tried the `fast_executemany` flag above and unfortunately it does not work with `Vertica`.