# How to improve the write speed to sql database using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to find a better way to push data to sql db using python. I have tried 
`dataframe.to_sql()` method and `cursor.fast_executemany()`
but they don't seem to increase the speed with that data(the data is in csv files) i'm working with right now. Someone suggested that i could use **named tuples** and **generators** to load data much faster than pandas can do.

[Generally the csv files are atleast 1GB in size and it takes around 10-17 minutes to push one file]

I'm fairly new to much of concepts of python,so please suggest some method or atleast a reference any article that shows any info. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc

Comment: When you say "sql database" do you mean Microsoft SQL Server? If so, are you using Microsoft's "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"?

Comment: yes my bad i forgot to mention it, it's for SQL server 17 using **driver:"SQL Server Native Client 11.0"**

Comment: re: "fast_executemany ... [doesn't] seem to increase the speed" - [This pyodbc issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/500) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert the csv as is into the database (i.e. without doing any processing in pandas), you could use sqlalchemy in python to execute a "BULK INSERT [params, file, etc.]". Alternatively, I've found that reading the csvs, processing, writing to csv, and then bulk inserting can be an option.

Otherwise, feel free to specify a bit more what you want to accomplish, how you need to process the data before inserting to the db, etc.