# INSERT INTO a whole list with python and SQL

Tags: python, sql

I'm inserting data in a database with INSERT INTO

The main problem is that I'm inserting around 170k points of data and I'm looping a code like that:

```
for row in data:
   SQL='''INSERT INTO Table
       VALUES ({},{},{})
   '''.format(row[0],row[1],row[2])
   cur.execute(SQL)
cur.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

This code is extremely slow, is there a faster way to do it?

I was thinking if there is a way to insert a whole column of my matrix data at once.

Comment: Check this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Basically you can achieve it using `executemany()` method.

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  .....
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

val = []
for row in data:
   val.append((row[0],row[1],row[2]))

sql = "INSERT INTO table (x,y,z) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Support may vary by DBMS (which you do not specify), but you can use a prepared statement, using your DBMS's `paramstyle` string in the VALUES clause, and pass a list of rows to the `executemany()` method.  See the docs at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-methods