# Using fast_executemany = True with sqlalchemy and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to speed up an import a Pandas DataFrame of shape `2.000.000 x 6` to a Postgres DB.

I am using:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://root:password@redshift_postgres.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev')
df.to_sql('table', 
          engine,
         if_exists='replace',
         schema='schema_1',
         index=False,
         method='multi',
         chunksize=10000,
         dtype={'column_1': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=30),
                'column_2': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=30),
                'column_3': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=200),
                'column_4':sqlalchemy.Date()})
```

And it is taking more than 20 minutes already which I suppose shouldn't. I've searched for methods to faster the process and [this seems the correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc). I am not sure if I am applying the method correctly:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
@event.listens_for(engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def receive_before_cursor_execute(
       conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany
        ):
            if executemany:
                cursor.fast_executemany = True

engine = create_engine('postgresql://root:password@redshift_postgres.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev')
df.to_sql('table', 
          engine,
         if_exists='replace',
         schema='schema_1',
         index=False,
         dtype={'column_1': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=30),
                'column_2': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=30),
                'column_3': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=200),
                'column_4':sqlalchemy.Date()})
```

Basically just adding the decorator and the function and removing `method=multi` and `chunksize=10000` from my previously written code.

Is there something trivial I am missing because it does not speed up the import at all?

Comment: `fast_executemany` is for mssql / pyodbc.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thank you, is there an alternative for Postgres?