# Importing large CSV file to SQL Server using Pythan

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm trying to import about 5 million records CSV file to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. The import wizard can't deliver that of course, so I tried to use python to do the work. This is my code:

```
import sqlalchemy, pyodbc, os
import pandas as pd

# upload the csv file
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\***\***\file.csv", index_col=0)

# stablish the connection
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=-hostname-\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'DATABASE=myDbs;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxx = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = cnxx.cursor()

# insert data into the database 
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Divys (ride_id, rideable_type, 
                start_time, end_time, start_station_name, 
                start_station_id, end_station_name, end_station_id, 
                start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, 
                member_casual, date_of_the_ride, year_of_the_ride, 
                quarter_of_the_ride, month_of_the_ride, day_of_week, 
                d1, d2, trip_duration_m)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                 ''',
                row.ride_id, 
                row.rideable_type,
                row.start_time, 
                row.end_time, 
                row.start_station_name, 
                row.start_station_id, 
                row.end_station_name, 
                row.end_station_id, 
                row.start_lat, 
                row.start_lng, 
                row.end_lat, 
                row.end_lng, 
                row.member_casual, 
                row.date_of_the_ride, 
                row.year_of_the_ride, 
                row.quarter_of_the_ride, 
                row.month_of_the_ride, 
                row.day_of_week, 
                row.d1, 
                row.d2, 
                row.trip_duration_m
                )
cnxx.commit()
```

This code was running for the last 24 hours without any result and it is jamming my memory. I like to know what should I do differently or if should I slice up the file to small pieces so it can be uploaded.

I really appreciate any help I get. Whether different Python or any other way to import large files to SQL Server. thank you.

Comment: does it work on a small CSV file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to speed up bulk insert to MS SQL Server using pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638136/how-to-speed-up-bulk-insert-to-ms-sql-server-using-pyodbc)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't beat the import wizard, probably you're doing something wrong