Improving write performance on SQL Server
I have a few million rows of data that needs to be transferred into another SQLServer DB and was testing the speed with a small number of rows.
Using the JDBC driver the best speed was 44 rows/s.
Then I switched to the SQL Spark connector which sped up the process significantly to 333 rows/s.
But this is still very slow and needed to know what I could do to increase the speed.
This is my code
df.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark")\
.mode("overwrite")\
.option("driver", driver2)\
.option("url", url2)\
.option("dbtable", table)\
.option("user", user2)\
.option("password", password2)\
.option("batchsize",batchsize)\
.option("reliabilityLevel","BEST_EFFORT")\
.save()


I'm running this on my local pc with 1 executor, 8 cores.
I have partitioned my dataframe into 8.
Using Spark v3.1.3 (for the sql connector)
I have tried changing the batch sizes and number of partitions, not sure if I'm tuning them correctly but have done a lot of trial and error.
When looking for ways to optimize I saw that people had an extremely fast speed for writing even before they optimized their code. So I'm not sure what the problem is anymore.
Edit: Using Pyspark is a requirement and at a later stage I would be live-streaming the data from multiple nodes. I am currently testing on my local system to familiarize myself with the works.
If there's a solution specific to the later stages that's different than when I do it locally, then please let me know.

Is your db server beefy enough to handle bulk insert?

@user238607 yes pretty sure it can

How big of batch sizes have you tried?

What is the source of the data? Can you use an SSIS package to do the transfer or use  BULK COPY ? I often move data between a physical office based server and a cloud server and speeds of 10k rows/second are common. Look at this answer.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638136/how-to-speed-up-bulk-insert-to-ms-sql-server-using-pyodbc and this https://pypi.org/project/bcpy/

@StrayCatDBA My last attempt was inserting 500k with batch size 50k which took almost 3min.

@AlanSchofield Data is in a cloud server. I have a requirement to use pyspark, since at a later stage I should be able to live-stream data. I will look into these as well thank you!
