Uploading very big files efficiently to a remote Microsoft SQL server from a Mac via Python
I want to upload the data of 1000 CSV files onto a remote Microsoft SQL Server from a Mac via Python. Each file has 5 columns and 10000000 rows. For the columns, three are of type float and two are of type string. The strings are not longer than 30 chars and the floats are not longer than 8 chars. I tried uploading just one of the files to the server using bulk-insert in sqlalchemy and it took 20 minutes. Doing the math, if I upload all 1000 files it would take approximately 333 hours which is way too long. I am sure the is a way to reduce the time but I don't know how. I would like to stick to python and not use another language/built-in server tools. Also, I don't think the problem is related to my internet speed or to too much server activity as I am the only one using the server.
So far I tried two different aproaches within SQL alchemy

Using .to_sql():

For this approach I used the following function:
def insert_data_in_chunks(df, engine, chunksize):
    total_rows = len(df)
    chunks = range(0, total_rows, chunksize)

    for start in chunks:
        end = min(start + chunksize, total_rows)
        chunk = df.iloc[start:end]
        chunk.to_sql('quotes_test', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi')
        print(f"Uploaded {end} of {total_rows} rows")

For this solution I had to cap the chunksize at 400 as .to_sql() seems to not be able to handle a bigger chunksize. I now their is a built-in chunksize option in .to_sql() but I wanted to keep track of the upload. Using this approach it would take months to upload all 1000 files.

Using SQLAlchemy's execute with Batching

For this approach, I used the following code:
with engine.connect() as conn:
    # Begin a transaction
    trans = conn.begin()
    try:
        for start in range(0, len(df), 10000):
            end = start + 10000
            batch = df.iloc[start:end]
            # Generate SQL insert statement
            sql = text("""
                INSERT INTO quotes_test (INSTRUMENT, BID, ASK, MID_PRICE, TIMESTAMP_UTC_YYYYMMDDhhmmss_sss)
                VALUES (:INSTRUMENT, :BID, :ASK, :MID_PRICE, :TIMESTAMP_UTC_YYYYMMDDhhmmss_sss)
            """)
            conn.execute(sql, batch.to_dict(orient='records'))
            print(f"Uploaded {end} of {len(df)} rows")
        # Commit transaction
        trans.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        trans.rollback()

This solution is much more efficient than the previous one. Each file takes 20 minutes to upload, yielding 333 hours to upload all the files, which is too long. I need a more efficient approach.

Forget sqlalchemy, use bulk inserts with pyodbc, it supports tvp:s which should be pretty fast.

comment above me is probably the better solution but this question might be relevant too

related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29638136/2144390

Or launch bcp.exe from python: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16

Or, since the MS-TDS protocol was designed for LAN use back in the 1990s and is highly sensitive to internet levels of latency, can you copy the files directly up to the SQL Server's file system and import them from there?
